# How to pass data from alert dialog fragment to recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a beginner in android how can i pass the data from alert dialog to recyclerview adapter because i cannot able to find the topic in internet or in stackoverflow

Comment: Please share with us some code and effort that you have done

Comment: Are you referring to `DialogFragment` rigth?

Answer (score 0):

An alert dialog is basically just an activity with a change to the `AndroidManifest.xml` so if you can create an activity and edit the theme in the manifest to something like this:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".DialogActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dialog"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert" />
```

You can treat the activity as any normal activity and add whatever you want from it to a recyclerview adapter. It would be helpful if you can share some of what you have attempted to better get an idea however.

Answer (score 0):

You need a callback. An interface will be implemented on the recyclerview host. Then the `DialogFragment` will use the life cycle to obtained the interface.

```
Interface Callback {
     void passData(YourObject object);
}
```

```
ActivityOrFragment extenda WHATEVER implements Callback {

    @Override
    void passData(YourObject object){adapter.addData(object);}
    //you have to create the method in the adapter and uodate usibg notify data set change or something suitable
}
```

```
YourDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private Callback callback;

   //If the recycler is in an activity
   @Override
   onAttach(Context contex){
        callback = (Callback) context;
   }

   //If the recycler is in a fragment
   @Override
    onViewCreated(...){
          //find the fragment and initialize the callback
         callback = getFragmentManager...
    }
}
```

The user probably interact with the dialog so once thar interqction is done use the callback

```
callback.passData(userCreatedObject);
```